# UIWebView's alpha setting and html content transparent background

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

[image]A `UIWebView` is added to a `UIView` as a subview.  The `UIView` has a white background color.

If I set the `UIWebView` to `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1];` The UIWebView will have a solid blue color.

If I set the alpha value to 0, the `UIWebView` takes on the (white) color of the `UIView`.  So the transparency is working.

But if I set alpha value to 0.5 (or anything between 0 and 1), the outcome looks like the picture.

By default html is set to transparent background.  I know you can manipulate html's body with this: `BODY { background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0) }`.  Event I set alpha to 0, it still would not take on the background of the webview (when webview's alpha is set to anything between 0 and 1)

My goal is to have the content area of the HTML to have the same color as the UIWebView.  In the picture, it should be almost purple color instead of almost blue.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @auspicious99: clarified my question.